# Creating point feature at intersection of two lines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, arcgis-10.5

How do I create a point feature at an intersection of highways and trails?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Intersecting](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) highways and trails with `output_type` Point:

> Point intersections will be returned. If the inputs are line or
>   polygon, the output will be a multipoint feature class.